# Redirect every index.php to his root folder

Tags: .htaccess

I'd like to know the `RewriteRule` to `redirect(301)` every `index.php` to their root.

For example, this url:

```
 http://www.example.com/folder/index.php
```

is redirected to:

```
 http://www.example.com/folder/
```

I need a generic rule to avoid `.htaccess` edit for each new folder.
The `.htaccess` will be placed on the root of the website.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?index\.php(\?*.*)$ $1/$2 [L,R=301]
```

This should take `/anyfolder/another/folder/index.php?a=1` and rewrite it to `/anyfolder/another/folder/?a=1` (GET variables optional, of course.)

Comment: Thank you for your response but it doesn't work. The model part is : RewriteRule ^index.php$

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "the model part".

I'll edit my answer and see if I can get it working.

Comment: I'm speaking about the matching pattern: ^index.php$

Comment: I edited the original post (and actually tried it out on my own) see if it works for you.

Comment: It doesn't work. It's not really a surprise because the matching pattern seems to take only the filename (index.php) and not any folder name.

Comment: That's what the ^(.*)/? in front of the index.php is for. Ah well. Good luck on finding the answer. Perhaps someone who is actually a mod_rewrite expert can help you.

Try tagging this with 'apache' and 'mod_rewite' and I think you'll get more attention.